# How to extract data from database by converting the data in condition?

Tags: php, laravel

English is not my default language and i feel very difficult to express my problems hope you will understand
I have a price table in database
Price table columns are

1. price
2. Futsal_id
3. time_id
4. date

In my controller, 
i get "Date" from the users.
First i convert this Date into Day

```
$date = $request->date;
$day = date("D",strtotime($date));
```

I want to extract data from database on the basis of "day" in "Date" column

Currently i am fetching data from database on the basis of date

```
$check = Price::where('futsal_id',$futsalid)->where('time_id',$timeid)->where('date',$date)->first();
```

So, My problem is how to convert **where('date',$date)** to **where('date',$day)** so that i can fetch data on the basis of day.
How to fetch data on the condition day by converting date to day in database and applying the condition.

Comment: Do you want just day (like 20) or full date without time (like 2020-05-20)?

Answer (score 0):

The `whereDay()` method may be used to compare a column's value against a specific day of a month:

```
$date = $request->date;
$day = date("d",strtotime($date));

$check = Price::where('futsal_id',$futsalid)->where('time_id',$timeid)->whereDay('date','20')->first();
```